# Block access to default vhost in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have an Apache 2.2 server which has Plesk installed.
I have spikes in CPU usage at the same time every day.

In the main logs I found the following accesses:

access_log

```
75.143.208.206 - [19/Jul/2015:07:49:32 +0100] "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.1" 89598ms 404 275 "-" "-"
```

error_log

```
[Sun Jul 19 07:49:32 2015] [error] [client 75.143.208.206] script '/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/xmlrpc.php' not found or unable to stat
```

Since they are accessing the default vhost they are getting an obvious 404 but the 404 shouldn't take 90 seconds, it should check if the file is there and return a 404 in less than a seconds.

What can I do to completely remove access to the default vhost or fix this problem which is causing ridiculous CPU spikes

Answer (score 0):

They're probably POSTing large amounts of data. It doesn't matter that the URL doesn't exist, that only gets checked after the request incuding POST data has been made.

You could forbid POST requests altogether in the default vhost; enable the rewrite module and put this in the default virtual host definition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```